# Lua - Sort table and randomize ties

Tags: sorting, random, lua, lua-table

I have a table with two values, one is a *name* (string and unique) and the other is a number value (in this case *hearts*). What I want is this: sort the table by *hearts* but scramble randomly the items when there is a tie (e.g. *hearts* is equal). By a standard sorting function, in case of ties the order is always the same and I need it to be different every time the sorting function works.
This is anexample:

```lua
tbl = {{name = "a", hearts = 5}, {name = "b", hearts = 2}, {name = "c", hearts = 6}, {name = "d", hearts = 2}, {name = "e", hearts = 2}, {name = "f", hearts = 7}}
sort1 = function (a, b) return a.hearts > b.hearts end
sort2 = function (a, b)
    if a.hearts ~= b.hearts then return a.hearts > b.hearts
    else return a.name > b.name end
end

table.sort(tbl, sort2)

local s = ""
for i = 1, #tbl do
    s = s .. tbl[i].name .. "(" .. tbl[i].hearts .. ") "
end
print(s)
```

Now, with the function `sort2` I think I quite got the problem. The problem is, what happens when `a.hearts == b.hearts`? In my code it just orders the ties by their name, not what I want. I have two ideas:

1. First scramble randomly all the items in the table, then apply `sort1`.
2. Add a value to every element of the table, called `rnd`, that is a random number. Then in `sort2`, when `a.hearts == b.hearts` order the items by `a.rnd > b.rnd`.
3. In `sort2`, when `a.hearts == b.hearts` generate randomly true or false and return it. It doesn't work, and I understand that this happens because the random true/false makes the order function crash since there could be inconsistencies.

I don't like 1 (because I would like to do everything inside the sorting function) and 2 (since it requires to add a value), I would like to do something like 3 but working. The question is: is there a way do to this in a simple manner, and what is an optimal way of doing this? (maybe, method 1 or 2 are optimal and I don't get it).

*Bonus question.* Moreover, I need to fix an item and sort the others. For example, suppose we want `"c"` to be first. Is it good to make a separate table with only the items to sort, sort the table and then add the fixed items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- example table
local tbl = {
  { name = "a", hearts = 5 },
  { name = "b", hearts = 2 },
  { name = "c", hearts = 6 },
  { name = "d", hearts = 2 },
  { name = "e", hearts = 2 },
  { name = "f", hearts = 7 },
}

-- avoid same results on subsequent requests
math.randomseed( os.time() )

---
-- Randomly sort a table
--
-- @param tbl Table to be sorted
-- @param corrections Table with your corrections
--
function rnd_sort( tbl, corrections )
   local rnd = corrections or {}
   table.sort( tbl,
      function ( a, b)
         rnd[a.name] = rnd[a.name] or math.random()
         rnd[b.name] = rnd[b.name] or math.random()
         return a.hearts + rnd[a.name] > b.hearts + rnd[b.name]
      end )
end

---
-- Show the values of our table for debug purposes
--
function show( tbl )
   local s = ""
   for i = 1, #tbl do
       s = s .. tbl[i].name .. "(" .. tbl[i].hearts .. ") "
   end
   print(s)
end

for i = 1, 10 do
   rnd_sort(tbl)
   show(tbl)
end

rnd_sort( tbl, {c=1000000} )  -- now "c" will be the first
show(tbl)
```

Comment: Wonderful! Just what I asked for, a very brilliant yet simple solution. Is important to note that this sorting function works only if _hearts_ are integers.

Comment: I would suggest to add some inline comments to describe the behind logic

Comment: @ValerioBozz - The `behind logic` term is too vague.  Which part of the solution is hard to understand for you?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I was only suggesting to introduce more inline comments :)

Comment: @ValerioBozz - Which lines of my code require additional inline comments?  AFAIU a [self-documenting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code) is better than a code with a lot of inline comments.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yup. "Code cannot explain the rationale behind why the program is being written or why it is implemented in such a way." It's good to be pro-active and share your thoughts, to respect other people time (but also to receive more +1).

Comment: @ValerioBozz - 1) IMO, the code is pretty clear.  Of course, I might be wrong.  As you are the only person who has claimed my code needs more comments, may I ask you what exactly in my code should be clarified by inline comments? 2) `the rationale behind why the program is being written` - because the author of the current SO question wants it to be written in such way :-)

Comment: I've added a note about `math.randomseed( os.time() )` that is not that obvious. Surely everything else is perfectly understandable as you say.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick function for shuffling (scrambling) numerically indexed tables:

```
function shuffle(tbl) -- suffles numeric indices
    local len, random = #tbl, math.random ;
    for i = len, 2, -1 do
        local j = random( 1, i );
        tbl[i], tbl[j] = tbl[j], tbl[i];
    end
    return tbl;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are free to introduce a new dependency, you can use [lazylualinq](https://github.com/Henkoglobin/lazylualinq) to do the job for you (or check out how it sorts sequences, if you do not need the rest):

```
local from = require("linq")

math.randomseed(os.time())

tbl = {{name = "a", hearts = 5}, {name = "b", hearts = 2}, {name = "c", hearts = 6}, {name = "d", hearts = 2}, {name = "e", hearts = 2}, {name = "f", hearts = 7}}

from(tbl)
    :orderBy("x => x.hearts")
    :thenBy("x => math.random(-1, 1)")
    :foreach(function(_, x) print(x.name, x.hearts) end)
```